# Finding objects in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I am trying to understand how to find object columns in dataset and I faced with a little problem

```
s = (X_train.dtypes == 'object')
object_cols = list(s[s].index)

print("Categorical variables:")
print(object_cols)
```

what s[s].index does here?

Answer (score 0):

If `s` is boolean mask then filter `s.index` from `X_train.columns` by this mask (if equal `True`) and convert values to `list`.

So it working like:

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('abc'),
                        'col2':list('ger'),
                        'col3':[4,5,6]})

s = (X_train.dtypes == 'object')
print(s)
col1     True
col2     True
col3    False
dtype: bool

print(s[s])
col1    True
col2    True
dtype: bool

object_cols = list(s[s].index)

print("Categorical variables:")
print(object_cols)
['col1', 'col2']

object_cols = list(X_train.columns[s])
print("Categorical variables:")
print(object_cols)
['col1', 'col2']
```

Comment: So, what s[s] do is only shows the booleans which are 'True' ?

Comment: @AshrafBadalov - exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to avoid this `s[s]` notation which can be confusing:

```
object_cols = X_train.select_dtypes('object').columns.tolist()

print("Categorical variables:")
print(object_cols)
```